# adding varying shaded area to faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to add shaded areas for each year of my data. Years are in rows, and shaded area should be the same for each row. Tried  a number of ways but nothing works with facets. Below is sample of data and latest code. The area which is supposed to be shaded is onset minus 10 days. I practically want to put a spotlight onto ten days of the 'season' across years. If there is smarter way of doing this, please advise me.
**The problem is that that shaded area does not match the data.**

Thanks in advance.

```
 ggplot(x) + 
geom_rect( aes(xmin = onset-10  , xmax = onset, 
                            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.4) +
geom_col(aes(x = days, y = irish_rules),size= 1)+
geom_col(aes(days, onset), fill = "black",width = 0.1)+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40) ) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank())+
facet_grid(years ~ stna)+
theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

Smple data:

```
    x <- structure(list(irish_rules = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 12, 0, 
16, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 
15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
18, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 37, 42, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
6, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
14, 25, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
16, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), years = c(1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L), days = c(121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 
125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 
136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 
147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 
158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 
169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 
180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 
191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 
202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 
213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 
224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 
235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 
189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 
200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 
211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 
222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 
233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 
121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 
132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 
143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 
154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 
165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 
176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 
187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 
198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 
209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 
220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 
231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 
242L, 243L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 
142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 
153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 
164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 
230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 
241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 
129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 
173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 
195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 
206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 
228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 
239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 
138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 
149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 
160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 
171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 
182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 
193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 
204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 
215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 
226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 
237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L), stna = c("Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", 
"Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Birr", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", "Casement", 
"Casement", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", 
"Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny", "Kilkenny"), onset = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 220, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 220, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 220, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 222, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 222, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 222, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("irish_rules", "years", 
"days", "stna", "onset"), row.names = c(NA, -738L), vars = "id", indices = list(
    0:122, 123:245, 246:368, 369:491, 492:614, 615:737), group_sizes = c(123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L), biggest_group_size = 123L, labels = structure(list(
    id = c("1983_Birr", "1983_Casement", "1983_Kilkenny", "1984_Birr", 
    "1984_Casement", "1984_Kilkenny")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame", vars = "id", .Names = "id"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to what the problem is with the code you have so far. You are already drawing a shaded area at onset minus 10 days.

Comment: Things hat might seem very obvious to you might not be so obvious to someone who is not an R expert. Shaded area on my plot was not what it was supposed to be according to values in observed and the answer below has got it right.

Comment: It did not seem very obvious to me, which is why I asked you for clarification. (Also see the guessing in the accepted answer.) I'm just trying to help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess what you might want to get.
Your onset contains many '0', and I have the feeling that this is not really what you want. Therefore, let's create a new column without '0' :

```
require(dplyr)
dat <- x %>% group_by(stna, years) %>% mutate(onset1 = max(onset))
```

Now I removed your 'black' shaded area, (and increased the alpha):

```
   ggplot(dat) + 
      geom_rect( aes(xmin = onset1-10  , xmax = onset1, 
                     ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.8) +
      geom_col(aes(x = days, y = irish_rules),size= 1)+
      #geom_col(aes(days, onset1), fill = "black",width = 0.1)+
      ... (the rest of your plot)
```

[image]

Note that I increased alpha because `geom_rect()` will draw one rectangle for each row ... (not ideal, but changing alpha very simple workaround)